# Octave: 'rgb2gray' undefined error

Tags: octave

Please advise what to do to make the `rgb2gray` work in Octave.
I found **[this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99136)**, but still I would like to use the `rgb2gray` functionality instead of manually calculating for each color channel.

The code that I run:

```
I = imread('smile.jpg');
G = rgb2gray(I);
```

The error I get:

```
error: 'rgb2gray' is undefined near line 10 column6
```

Additional:
Octave version: 3.6.4
Image package is installed. Version: 2.0.0.
The 'rgb2gray.m' is installed in C:\Octave\share\octave\packages\image-2.0.0

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't load your packages. When you type `pkg list` you can find which ones are loaded by an asterisk in front of their names. Load a package with `pkg load image`.

Having to load a packages is that thing that most users find strange but if you compare with other languages, such as Python, Perl, or C++, would you expect them to `import`, `use`, or `#include` every libraries available in the system by default? See [Octave's FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error) for more details.

Comment: WooW. It worked. Super. 
Thanks. 
Sorry can vote up. Do not have the rating yet. 
Your explanation regarding `import` now makes perfect sense.

Comment: @vbnk you should at least still be able to mark it as the correct answer. Something like a grayed check button under the downvote button.

Answer (score 0):

The function rgb2ntsc has historically been part of Octave (I mean historically, since 1994). However, since Octave version 4.4 (released in 2018), the function was moved from Octave to the Octave Forge image package. It is part of the Octave Forge image package since its 2.8.0 version (released in 2018).

Basically, how to use rgb2ntsc depends on what version you have:

Octave >= 4.4.0
You need to install and load the image package version 2.8.0 or later (the latest is 2.12.0).

```
octave> pkg install -forge image
octave> pkg load image
```

unfortunately, it did not work for me. So I use the code, and it works. which is  from [Octave rgb2ntsc missing in latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165479/octave-rgb2ntsc-missing-in-latest-version)

```
    function yiq_img = rgb2ntsc(rgb_img)
%RGB2NTSC Transform a colormap or image from red-green-blue (RGB) 
%   color space to luminance-chrominance (NTSC) space. 
%   The input may be of class uint8, uint16, single, or double. 
%   The output is of class double.

% https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/rgb2ntsc.html

if isa(rgb_img, 'uint8') || isa(rgb_img, 'uint16') || ...
        isa(rgb_img, 'double')
    
    red = rgb_img(:, :, 1);
    green = rgb_img(:, :, 2);
    blue = rgb_img(:, :, 3);
    
    y = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;
    i = 0.596 * red - 0.274 * green - 0.322 * blue;
    q = 0.211 * red - 0.523 * green + 0.312 * blue;
    
    yiq(:, :, 1) = y;
    yiq(:, :, 2) = i;
    yiq(:, :, 3) = q;
    
    yiq_img = double(yiq);
else
    error('Input image datatype is not supported')
end

end
```

I am viewing the week5 lecture notes by Andrew Ng. AI machine learning course. https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/resources/EcbzQ

refer to: [Octave rgb2ntsc missing in latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165479/octave-rgb2ntsc-missing-in-latest-version)