# Octave rgb2ntsc missing in latest version

Tags: octave, data-analysis

I am doing one course where they have sample example which reads image and create 20.20 pix.
There is rgb2ntsc but it's not available in the latest version of Octave.
What will be substitute for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether the below answer your question, but I wrote the code, using the [source](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/rgb2ntsc.html):

```
function yiq_img = rgb2ntsc(rgb_img)
%RGB2NTSC Transform a colormap or image from red-green-blue (RGB) 
%   color space to luminance-chrominance (NTSC) space. 
%   The input may be of class uint8, uint16, single, or double. 
%   The output is of class double.

% https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/rgb2ntsc.html

if isa(rgb_img, 'uint8') || isa(rgb_img, 'uint16') || ...
        isa(rgb_img, 'double')
    
    red = rgb_img(:, :, 1);
    green = rgb_img(:, :, 2);
    blue = rgb_img(:, :, 3);
    
    y = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;
    i = 0.596 * red - 0.274 * green - 0.322 * blue;
    q = 0.211 * red - 0.523 * green + 0.312 * blue;
    
    yiq(:, :, 1) = y;
    yiq(:, :, 2) = i;
    yiq(:, :, 3) = q;
    
    yiq_img = double(yiq);
else
    error('Input image datatype is not supported')
end

end
```

How to ensure the code is working?

Example:

```
>>> I = rgb2ntsc(imread('samur.jpeg'));
>>> imshow(I)
```

where

[image]

Converted to:

[image]

Comment: I like this answer better than the _otter_ one.  (otter puns rule!)

Answer (score 1):

rgb2ntsc is a function of image package

https://octave.sourceforge.io/image/function/rgb2ntsc.html

to use it, load the `image` package if installed

```
octave:2> pkg load image
octave:3> help rgb2ntsc
'rgb2ntsc' is a function from the file /usr/share/octave/packages/image-2.12.0/rgb2ntsc.m

 -- YIQ_MAP = rgb2ntsc (RGB_MAP)
 -- YIQ_IMG = rgb2ntsc (RGB_IMG)
     Transform a colormap or image from red-green-blue (RGB) color space
     to luminance-chrominance (NTSC) space.  The input may be of class
     uint8, uint16, single, or double.  The output is of class double.

     Implementation Note: The reference matrix for the transformation is

          /Y\     0.299  0.587  0.114  /R\
          |I|  =  0.596 -0.274 -0.322  |G|
          \Q/     0.211 -0.523  0.312  \B/

     as documented in <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ> and truncated
     to 3 significant figures.  Note: The FCC version of NTSC uses only
     2 significant digits and is slightly different.

     See also: ntsc2rgb, rgb2hsv, rgb2ind.
```

Comment: Well, yes, but, have you seen the _otter_ answer? It's otter-worldly! You otter upvote that too.

Answer (score 1):

The function `rgb2ntsc` has historically been part of Octave (I mean historically, since 1994). However, since Octave version 4.4 (released in 2018), the function was moved from Octave to the Octave Forge image package.  It is part of the Octave Forge image package since its 2.8.0 version (released in 2018).

Basically, how to use `rgb2ntsc` depends on what version you have:

### Octave >= 4.4.0

You need to install and load the image package version 2.8.0 or later (the latest is 2.12.0).

```
octave> pkg install -forge image
octave> pkg load image
```

### Octave < 4.4.0

You don't have to do anything, `rgb2ntsc` will already be available.